# Jenkins Pipeline emailext $class parameter for recipientProviders

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have been trying to get my head around the pipeline groovy code below:

```
emailext (
        subject: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
        body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
          <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
      )
```

1) Does the dollar sign before the class (which is $class) have some special meaning? I know it refers to the class type `DevelopersRecipientProvider` but is `$class` some sort of special reserved word in groovy to indicate class type?

2) In the source code, `recipientProviders` is a `List` but what exactly is being assigned to it in the code above? Is it a list of maps?

3) Where is emailext defined in the email ext plugin source code? I searched for emailext in all the .groovy files in the plugin source code but can't seem to find something that looks like the emailext call above.

I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on the above, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) 2) is about the same things:

`[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']` is a map literal with key `'$class'`(note it is a string literal) and value `'DevelopersRecipientProvider'`. Nothing special.

About `recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]`,

`[[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]`is a list of map, `'recipientProviders'` is the key same as `'subject'` or `'body'`.

You may think the `emailext` is a method with signature: `void emailext(Map<String, Object> map)`

3) `emailext` is a method implemented in Java. You can find source code [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/2177dd5762f2e024856e6c6fb6564ae13fc776a9/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/EmailExtStep.java#L241) and [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/04efc239ca882a411414ebadc6785bc21aa0910f/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/EmailType.java#L18).

Answer (score 7):

To add, the `$class` literal *is* a special key used by the Jenkins Pipeline. When editing a pipeline job, set the script source to inline (not SCM) and there is a link to the syntax reference. In that section there is a sub-section "Steps Reference" which is at `https://<jenkins url>/job/<job name>/pipeline-syntax/html`.

> As maps of parameters. Default values may be omitted. (Note that `[1, 2, 3]` is a list in Groovy whereas `[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]` is a map.)
>
> The special map key `$class` is used to represent the simple or (where necessary) fully-qualified class name of the object being requested. `$class` may be omitted where the containing parameter allows only a single kind of nested object (or list of them):
>
> `checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git://…'], extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']]])`
>
> In this example, `GitSCM` must be specified to distinguish the kind of `SCM` used by the `delegate` of `checkout` (the single mandatory parameter name delegate can be omitted), and `CleanBeforeCheckout` must be specified to distinguish the kind of `GitSCMExtension` used by the `extensions` of `GitSCM` — a “heterogeneous” list; but `$class: 'UserRemoteConfig'` may be omitted since the `userRemoteConfigs` of `GitSCM` are defined to contain only `UserRemoteConfig`s — it is a “homogeneous” list. (No such omission is permitted for homogeneous lists in the first syntax.)
>
> Note that in cases where a single parameter is given, with the name omitted, and that parameter is a map, it must be enclosed in parentheses to avoid a syntactic ambiguity.