# $class syntax in jenkins scripted dsl

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Often when looking at scripted jenkins pipeline code, I see this pattern...

```
step([$class: 'GitHubSetCommitStatusBuilder',
        statusMessage: [content: 'Pipeline Started']])
```

I have not had any luck finding documentation on this technique and would love it if someone could explain what this is doing and when/why it is useful.  I believe this is a way to instantiate and populate the members of an underlying groovy class - but more detail would be appreciated.

Also is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 13):

Here is [a reference](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) that briefly explains the syntax. Basically, you are providing the step() function a map of arguments in the form of name-value pairs. The first argument which is especially denoted by the name $class tells the function which class (plugin) to instantiate.

It also seems that this syntax is being deprecated in favor of shorter syntax, also explained in the same link.

​

Comment: Pipeline docs was moved to https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/ which unfortunately omits to document what the $class implies - but this SO post actually does explain $class properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773181/jenkins-pipeline-emailext-class-parameter-for-recipientproviders

Comment: I do not believe that this technique is deprecated or at least I could not find any reference to the fact of deprecation. Many plugins rely on specifying the arguments to their functions in this form. It is just sub-optimal from a plugin-development perspective.

Answer (score 3):

There's also another quick reference from "Pipeline: Basic Steps" github repo documentation :

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/CORE-STEPS.md

> **Syntax**
>
> As an example, you can write a Pipeline script:

```
node {
    sh 'make something'
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'something'])
}
```

> Here we are running the standard Archive the artifacts post-build action (hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver), and configuring the Files to archive property (artifacts) to archive our file something produced in an earlier step. The easiest way to see what class and field names to use is to use the Snippet Generator feature in the Pipeline configuration page.
>
> See the compatibility list for the list of currently supported steps.
>
> **Simplified syntax**
>
> Build steps and post-build actions in Jenkins core as of 2.2, and in some plugins according to their individual changelogs, have defined symbols which allow for a more concise syntax. Snippet Generator will offer this when available. For example, the above script may also be written:

```
node {
    sh 'make something'
    archiveArtifacts 'something'
}
```

NB: The Simplified syntax, makes reference to [Plugin Steps parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/)

Comment: How would this look in a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with this syntax, but unfortunately have not found any doc yet.

I guess this syntax is used to doing the instance initialization.

All step classes implement interface `BuildStep`. After script loaded, all step instances initiated, then their `perform` method are invoked during build procedure.

All above is my conjecture.