# Understanding Jenkins pipeline email code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm very new to Jenkins pipeline and going through some tutorials. During that I came across code like following -

```
post {
        always {
            emailext body: 'A Test EMail', 
             recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Test'
        }
    }
```

In the above code, for `recipientProviders` there is value as an array having `$class` as key with some value. From that I could guess some of the thing but not able to understand exactly how those `$class` values are identified and what is exactly meaning of that statement.

I could not find documentation which helps to understand it. Could you please help me to understand above code or point me to relevant document?

Answer (score 0):

This [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773893/598141) should provide an explanation.

There is also a [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3604514#content/view/3604514) and the [Jenkins pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/) page.